# Locked delayed_job row lingers in the database after capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

Whenever I deploy with capistrano or run `cap production delayed_job:restart`, I end up with the currently-running delayed_job row remaining locked.

The delayed_job process is successfully stopped, a new delayed_job process is started, and a new row is locked by the new process. The problem is that the last process' row is still sitting there & marked as locked. So I have to go into the database manually, delete the row, and then manually add that job back into the queue for the new delayed_job process to get to.

Is there a way for the database cleanup & re-queue of the previous job to happen automatically?

Comment: Apparently, it doesn't happen all the time. I just did a deploy with migrations & my database table was nice and clean afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. This happens whenever a job is forcibly killed. Part of the problem is that worker processes are managed by the daemons gem rather than delayed_job itself. I'm currently investigating ways to fix this, such as:

- Setting a longer timeout before daemons forcibly terminates (nothing about this in docs for delayed_joob or daemons)
- Clearing locks before starting delayed_job workers

I'll post back here whan and if I come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

#### Adjust your Daemon wait time or raise an exception on `SIGINT`.

@John Carney is correct. In short, all `delayed_job` workers get sent something like a `SIGINT` (nice interrupt) on a redeploy. `delayed_job` workers, by default, will complete their current job (if they are working on one) and then gracefully terminate.

However, if the job that they are working on is a longer-running job, there's an amount of time the Daemon manager waits before it gets annoyed and sends a more serious interrupt signal, like a `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL`. This wait time and what gets sent really depends on your setup and configuration.

When that happens, the `delayed_job` worker gets killed immediately without being able to finish the job it is working on or even cleanup after itself and mark the job as no longer locked.

This ends up in a "stranded" job that is marked as "locked" but locked to a process/worker that no longer exists. Not good.

That's the crux of the issue and what is happening. To get around this, you have two main options, depending on your what your jobs look like (we use both):

#### 1. Raise an exception when an interrupt is received.

You can do this by setting the `raise_signal_exceptions` configuration to either `:term` or `true`:

```rb
Delayed::Worker.raise_signal_exceptions = :term
```

This configuration options accepts `:term`, `true` or `false` (default). You can read more on the original commit [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/90579c3047099b6a58595d4025ab0f4b7f0aa67a).

I would try first with `:term` and see if that solves your issue. If not, you may need to set it to `true`.

Setting to `:term` or `true` will gracefully raise an exception and unlock the job for another `delayed_job` worker to pickup the job and start working on it.

Setting it to `true` means that your `delayed_job` workers won't even attempt to finish the current job that they are working on. They will just immediately raise an exception, unlock the job and terminate themselves.

#### 2. Adjust how your workers are interrupted/terminated/killed on a redeploy.

This really depends on your redeploy, etc. In our case, we are using Cloud66 to handle deploys so we just had to configure this with them. But this is what ours looks like:

```yaml
stop_sequence: int, 172800, term, 90, kill # Allows long-running delayed jobs to finish before being killed (i.e. on redeploy). Sends SIGINT, waits 48 hours, sends SIGTERM, waits 90 seconds, sends SIGKILL.
```

On a redeploy, this tells the Daemon manager to follow these steps with each `delayed_job` worker:

1. Send a `SIGINT`.
2. Wait 172800 seconds (2 days) - we have *very* long-running jobs.
3. Send a `SIGTERM`, if the worker is still alive.
4. Wait 90 seconds.
5. Send a `SIGKILL`, if the worker is still alive.

---

Anyway, that should help get you on the right track to configuring this properly for yourself.

We use both methods by setting a lengthy timeout as well as raising an exception when a `SIGTERM` is received. This ensures that if there is a job that runs past the 2 day limit, it will at least raise an exception and unlock the job, allowing us to investigate instead of just leaving a stranded job that is locked to a process that no longer exists.